# Predicative definition of the natural number set in a Complete Field

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

Usually inside a Complete Field CF, the natural number set in a Complete Field $(\Bbb N_{CF})$ is defined as intersection of all inductive sets in CF, where the inductive set definition is as fallow: 
If our CF is (F,+,$*$,$e^+$,$e^*$,P) where P is named the positive subset of F, and K $\subset$ F, then 
K is inductive in our CF if 
(1) $e^+$ $\in $ K  and 
(2) ($\forall$x)($x\in $K $\Rightarrow$ (x + $e^*$) $\in $ K

Now suppose I define the "Naturalness" predicate in CF as

(1) K $\subset$ P
(2) $e^+$ $\in $ K  and 
(3) ($\forall$x)($x\in $ K $\Rightarrow$ (x + $e^*$) $\in $ K and 
(4) ($\forall$n)($n\in $ K)($\forall$ x)(x $\in$ F) if (n < x and x < (n + $e^*$)) $\Rightarrow$ x $\notin $ K

My question is: Given a set S $\subset$ F then S is Naturalness $\Leftrightarrow$ S = $\Bbb N_{CF}$

Note: Thanks to @Wojowu that thanks to his comments, I made a refinement of the original question.

Comment: Letting $K=\Bbb Z$ and $F=\Bbb R$ also satisfies this, so this doesn't work.

Comment: No, Integers is not a inductive set. There is no way to show that -1 belong to any inductive set.

Comment: I meant that it satisfies your naturalness predicate.

Comment: My naturalness predicate is build in a way that if a set S is naturalness is also inductive so if Integer is not inductive is also not naturalness. Notice both predicates (naturalness and inductive) share the condition (1) and (2).

Comment: Actually, $\Bbb Z$ is inductive - if $n$ is an integer, so is $n+1$. Also, I believe you want your (2) to have $x+e^*$, not $x+e^+$ (the latter is just $x$).

Comment: Z is not inductive but you are right is x + e*. Thank you! I will change it now.

Comment: Please explain why you say $\Bbb Z$ is not inductive.

Comment: The intersection of *all* inductive sets is empty; you want to take the intersection of all inductive sets containing 0.

Comment: Z is inductive, thank you again. I have to reformulate "naturalness" in a more restrictive way. Thank you a lot.

Comment: When you write "complete field", how do you define completeness, in particular? By the least upper bound property, or via Cauchy sequences?

Comment: I mean thank you a lot Wojowu.

Comment: Carl: e+ is for definition in all inductive set.

Comment: Carl: e+ is for definition in all inductive set. On the other hand when you work with structures what is important is that you can do thing thanks to basics properties, not how. The firsts two pages of http://www.math.fsu.edu/~bellenot/class/su13/found/other/reals.pdf would be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know how completeness interacts with the other conditions mentioned here. Below, "natural number" means a natural number in the usual sense, not an element of the field.

If the field is archimedean, then suppose $S$ satisfies your naturalness condition. Note that then $n \cdot 1  = 1 + \ldots + 1$, the sum of $n$ ones, is in $S$ for any $n$ in the (ordinary) natural numbers. Now consider any positive field element $k$. By archimedeanness, $k < n\cdot 1$ for some natural number $n$, hence for a minimal such $n$. Then $(n-1) \cdot 1 \leq k < n \cdot 1$ by minimality of $n$ and the fact that the ordering is total, and so your last clause entails that either $k = (n - 1) \cdot 1$ or $k \notin S$. Thus $S$ consists precisely of elements of the form $n \cdot 1$, which is equivalent to the first definition you give.

On the other hand, if the field is non-archimedean, let $k$ be an element of the field which is greater than $n \cdot 1$ for every natural number $n$. Then the set $S$ of elements of the form $n \cdot 1 + m \cdot k$ for $n$ a natural number and $m$ equal to either $0$ or $1$ satisfies your naturalness predicate, but is not the minimal inductive set (which is the subset where $m = 0$). The last clause is the only one that is not immediately clear. We'll show it by condradiction, i.e. if $x \in S$ is between two elements of $S$ differing by $1$, a contradiction follows. So suppose we have that $n \cdot 1 + m \cdot k < s\cdot 1 + t \cdot k < (n+1) \cdot 1 + m \cdot k$, where our arbitrary $x \in S$ has been written as $s \cdot 1 + t \cdot k$. Now if $t = 0$ and $m=1$ we have $(s-n)\cdot 1 > k$, a contradiction of the defining property of $k$ (that it be greater than all numbers $n \cdot 1$). Similarly, if $m = 0$ and $t=1$ then we have $k < (n+1-s)\cdot 1$, again impossible. Thus $t = m$. So we can subtract $t\cdot k=m\cdot k$ from everything and get $n\cdot 1 < s \cdot 1 < (n+1)\cdot 1$. But we know that this is impossible, because the ordering of elements of the form $n \cdot 1$ is the same as that of ordinary natural numbers.